# Website aggregators

Tags: google, search-engine-indexing

I have a marketplace website (with 1.5 m pages), these pages has categories with items that links directly to another site, google is very poor indexing it (only main page without subpages). Google is poor indexing marketplaces / websites without unique content?

Comment: See [What is duplicate content and how can I avoid being penalized for it on my site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35652/what-is-duplicate-content-and-how-can-i-avoid-being-penalized-for-it-on-my-site)